# How to implement file browsing in iOS as it does not have built-in functionality in Xcode

Tags: ios

My issue is how I can open a file selector in iPhone as on `UIButton` click which can access all files stored in iPhone device.

Comment: files like image and video or all type of file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your iPhone App cannot access all the files present on the Device. However, your app can access that its own sandbox i.e. document directory of the app (its own).

Comment: So, considering this, How can I upload file from my iphone device to Cloud database e.g. Amazon or Google Drive. Is it possible?

Comment: @Ashwin The file which you want to upload to Amazon or Google Drive is created by your app?

Comment: No, Uploading an existing file.

Comment: @Ashwin What you can do at last is copy the file to your app's sandbox from other app.

Comment: which built-in app I can use for this?

Comment: First tell me which file you want to upload on Amazon or Google Drive? Image from Photo Gallery?

Comment: Image would be taken from Camera or Gallery and it can be uploaded. But document which is either created by your app or copy from other app's sandbox can only be uploaded to these cloud services.

Comment: It means there is no app in iphone which can upload existing image or document which is not created by own application?